# why is the site zoomed in on mobile phone (bulma)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, footer, bulma

**production site**: http://www.kpft.org

**observations**: on mobile device site is slightly zoomed in, which cuts off the right-hand side of the page contents. except the for the footer. for some reason the footer is completely visible and does not stretch to the width of the device.

**expected behavior**: footer should stretch the full width of the mobile device - which it does on desktop. and the site should not be zoomed in on mobile - which it does not do on desktop.

**attempts**: i saw a similar question, but the issue was around the footer's 'minimum width' which doesn't appear to be my issue here. i did try adding *min-width: 100% !important* just in case but was not successful. thank you!

Expected:
[image: top of home page should span the width of the mobile device]

Actual:
[image: instead, it is zoomed in upon arrival]

Expected Footer:
[image: site footer should span the width of the mobile device]

Actual Footer:
[image: instead the footer does not reach the full width and the initial zoom appears to span the width of this footer]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    
    <title>KPFT | Houston's Community Station</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="kpft_favicon.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>

<style> 
    html {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); scroll-behavior: smooth;}
    body {font-family: "Fredoka One"; font-size: 1em;}
    
    /*.is-fullheight-100vh {height: 100vh;}*/
    
    .navbar {background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .05);}
    .navbar-menu {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) !important;}
    
    .navblock {color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75); transition: color 1s,  background-color 1s;}
    .navblock:hover {color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;}

    .kpft:hover {background-color: rgba(183,22,22,.5) !important;}
    .hd1:hover {background-color: rgba(111,221,5,.5) !important;}
    .hd2:hover {background-color: rgba(7,89,250,.5) !important;}
    .archive:hover {background-color: rgba(251,214,6,.5) !important;}
    .calendar:hover {background-color: rgba(175,7,250,.5) !important;}
    .poll:hover {background-color: rgba(251,135,7,.5) !important;}
    .fb:hover {background-color: rgba(114,7,250,.5) !important;}
    .insta:hover {background-color: rgba(251,5,15,.5) !important;}
    
    audio {opacity: .25; transition: opacity 1s;}
    audio:hover {opacity: 1;}
    
    .button {background-color: rgba(111, 221, 5, .35); color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); border: 1px rgba(111, 221, 5, .5); transition: background-color 1s;}
    .button:hover {background-color: rgba(111,221,5, .5); color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);}
    
    .footer {padding: 3em; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .05); color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25); transition: color 1s;}
    .footer:hover {color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);}
</style>

<body>
    
    <div class="columns">
        
        <div class="column">
            
            <nav class="navbar is-size-4 is-fixed-top" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
                
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
                        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                
                <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
                    
                    <div class="navbar-start">
                        <a class="navbar-item navblock kpft" href="#footer"><p class="is-size-3">KPFT</p></a>
                        <a class="navbar-item navblock hd1" href="#hd1">
                            <p class="is-size-3"><i class="fas fa-dog"></i>&nbsp&nbsp</p>
                            <audio controls><source src="https://streams.pacifica.org:9000/live_64" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
                        </a>
                        <a class="navbar-item navblock hd2" href="#hd2">
                            <p class="is-size-3"><i class="fas fa-cat"></i>&nbsp&nbsp</p>
                            <audio controls>
                             <source src="https://streams.pacifica.org:9000/HD3_64" type="audio/mpeg">
                            </audio>
                        </a>
                        <a class="navbar-item navblock archive" href="https://archive.kpft.org/" target="_blank"><p class="is-size-3"><i class="fas fa-dove"></i></p></a>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="navbar-end">
                        <a class="navbar-item navblock calendar" href="https://theblueshound.com/music-calendar" target="_blank"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></a>
                        <a class="navbar-item navblock poll" href="https://kpftradio.getform.com/q4w51" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-poll"></i></a>
                        <a class="navbar-item navblock fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/kpfthouston" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a class="navbar-item navblock insta" href="https://www.instagram.com/kpfthouston/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        <div class="navbar-item">
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <a class="button" href="https://afg.secureallegiance.com/kpft/WebModule/Donate.aspx?P=WEB20&PAGETYPE=PLG&CHECK=RmCkD65dLKTiQl%2byqVkEd4HJipnY8PNT" target="_blank">Donate</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
            </nav>
            
        </div>
        
        <div>
            
            <section class="hero is-fullheight">
                
                <div class="hero-body">
                    
                    <div class="container has-text-centered">
                        
                        <div class="columns" style="margin-top: 2.5em; margin-bottom: 2.5em;">
                            <div class="column">
                                <p class="title is-size-1" style="color: rgba(111,221,5, 1);"><i class="fas fa-person-booth fa-2x"></i></p>
                                <div style="margin-bottom: 2.5em;">
                                    <p class="is-size-1" style="color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);">Voting ends in</p>
                                    <p class="is-size-3" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" id="timer"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="columns is-mobile">
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <a class="navblock" href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdhxI__g1Rxi4tlJPZOgI-0cJclhQOskMdsWws9-8O6U62enw/viewform" target="_blank">
                                            <p class="is-size-2"><i class="fas fa-vote-yea fa-2x"></i></p>  
                                            <p class="is-size-6">Request ballot</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <a class="navblock" href="https://elections.pacifica.org/candstmt/cand_list.php" target="_blank">
                                            <p class="is-size-2"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></p>   
                                            <p class="is-size-6">Watch candidates</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <a class="navblock" href="https://elections.pacifica.org/wordpress/youtube-channel/" target="_blank">
                                            <p class="is-size-2"><i class="fas fa-scroll fa-2x"></i></p>    
                                            <p class="is-size-6">Read statements</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br><div class="columns is-mobile">
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <a class="navblock" href="https://elections.pacifica.org/wordpress/voter-guide/" target="_blank">
                                            <p class="is-size-2"><i class="fas fa-book-reader fa-2x"></i></p>   
                                            <p class="is-size-6">Read voter guide</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <a class="navblock" href="https://elections.pacifica.org/" target="_blank">
                                            <p class="is-size-2"><i class="fas fa-globe fa-2x"></i></p> 
                                            <p class="is-size-6">Visit elections site</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <a class="navblock" href="https://elections.pacifica.org/wordpress/election-information/stv-faq/" target="_blank">
                                            <p class="is-size-2"><i class="fas fa-people-arrows fa-2x"></i></p> 
                                            <p class="is-size-6">Single Transferable Voting</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br><p class="is-size-5" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);">Cast your ballot for Local Station Board (LSB) Delegates before 10:59pm CDT Friday 10/15!</p>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        
                        <figure class="image is-inline-block" style="max-width: 100%; margin: 0 0 2em 0;">
                            <img src="images/kpft_banner.jpg">
                        </figure>
                        
                        <div class="columns">
                            
                            <div class="column is-one-third">
                                <p class="title is-size-3" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);"><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i></p>
                                <p class="subtitle is-size-5" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);">Station Updates<p>
                                <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkpfthouston&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;border-radius:1em;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="column is-two-thirds">
                                
                                <div id="hd1" class="columns" style="background-color: rgba(111, 221, 5,.25); border-radius: 2em; margin: 2.5em; padding: 1em;">
                                    
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <p class="title is-size-3" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);"><i class="fas fa-dog"></i></p>
                                        <p class="subtitle is-size-5" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);">HD1 Channel 90.1 FM<br><a href="https://confessor.kpft.org/playlist/pub_sched.php" target="_blank" class="is-size-6">Schedule</a></p>
                                        <audio controls>
                                         <source src="https://streams.pacifica.org:9000/live_64" type="audio/mpeg">
                                        </audio>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <iframe src="pl_current_fm.php" style="height: 11em;  opacity: .75; border-radius: 1em;"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div id="hd2" class="columns" style="background-color: rgba(7,89,250,.25); border-radius: 2em; margin: 2.5em; padding: 1em;">
                                    
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <p class="title is-size-3" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);"><i class="fas fa-cat"></i></p>
                                        <p class="subtitle is-size-5" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);">HD2 Channel Internet<br><a href="https://hd3.kpft.org/playlist/pub_sched.php" target="_blank" class="is-size-6">Schedule</a></p>
                                        <audio controls>
                                         <source src="https://streams.pacifica.org:9000/HD3_64" type="audio/mpeg">
                                        </audio>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <iframe src="https://hd3.kpft.org/playlist/pl_current.php" style="height: 11em;  opacity: .75; border-radius: 1em;"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div style="margin: 2em;">
                            <p class="title is-size-3" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);"><i class="fas fa-broadcast-tower"></i></p>
                            <p class="subtitle is-size-5" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);">Broadcast Range</p>
                            <figure class="image is-inline-block" style="max-width: 100%; margin: 0 0 2em 0;">
                                <img src="images/kpft_broadcast_range.png">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
            </section>
            
        </div>
        
        <footer id="footer" class="footer has-text-centered">
            <figure class="image is-inline-block" style="max-width: 25%;">
                <img src="images/kpft_logo.png">
            </figure>
            <p class="is-size-6">(713) 526-5738</p>
            <p class="is-size-6"><a href="https://publicfiles.fcc.gov/fm-profile/kpft" target="_blank">FCC Public File</a></p>
            <p class="is-size-6">419 Lovett Blvd, Houston, TX 77006</p>
            <p class="is-size-6">All Rights Reserved 90.1 KPFT © 2021</p>
            <iframe src="https://kpft.org/kpft_sched.php" style="height: 400px; margin-top: 2em;"></iframe>
        </footer>
        
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Check for click events on the navbar burger icon
      $(".navbar-burger").click(function() {

          // Toggle the "is-active" class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
          $(".navbar-burger").toggleClass("is-active");
          $(".navbar-menu").toggleClass("is-active");

      });
    });
    
    var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 15, 2021 22:59:00").getTime();
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000*60*60*24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000*60*60*24)) / (1000*60*60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000*60)) / 1000);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + " days • " + hours + " h • " + minutes + " m • " + seconds + " s";
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("timer".innerHTML = "Thank you for voting!");
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: please make a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE like a photograph?

Comment: maybe the shortest code required to reproduce the problem. more info: [mre]

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE sure... i mean i plan to recreate from scratch in case no one has ever run into this problem. in the meantime i've added some screenshots and the code which is quite minimal to begin with.

Comment: your problem lies inside the `.column is-two-thirds` if you delete this, the page and footer fills the whole page as expected

Comment: thanks @davbuc. i decided to switch to bulma's tile feature and that seems to work for the most part. the Facebook plugin iframe is spilling outside of its div, but it's a lot better than before.